# Conjugacy classes in $GL_2(\mathbb Z/p^k\mathbb Z)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

It is not too hard to classify the conjugacy classes of $\mathbb GL_2(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$ based on the splitting of it's characteristic polynomial. Now let us consider the Artin ring $R_k = \mathbb Z/p^k\mathbb Z$ and the matrix group $G_k = GL_2(R_k)$. Reducing modulo the maximal ideal, conjugacy classes of $GL_2(R_k)$ give rise to conjugacy classes of $GL_2(R_{k-1})$.

What can be said about this map? Is is surjective? Injective? If not, how big can the fibers be? Do they grow with $k$?

Comment: It certainly is surjective since the map on the actual groups is surjective (since $\mathrm{GL}_2$ is smooth). It is certainly not injective. I mean, one way to think about this is to choose lifts of elements of $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ to $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ and compute their centralizers. These will be smooth, assuming that your lift is 'semisimple', and so the centralizers will surject onto their points in $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ and will have to grow unless they're zero dimensional.